# PhoneGap: Overlaying a connection status bar

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an app using PhoneGap with HTML/CSS/JS delivered by the client. As such, I can't touch any of the contents of `/www`. They now want a current connection status to be overlaid over the web view.

If I could modify the JS, I could make use of the Connection plugin and overlay the bar in the HTML application but unfortunately that's not an option.

I'm a bit stuck on where to start. I'm using the Cordova CLI to generate my project. I was wondering about a local plugin that handles the functionality I need, perhaps even extending from the PhoneGap Connection plugin, but I don't really know where to start.

This only has to work in Android at the moment.

Any guidance gratefully received.

Comment: you are developing using PhoneGap but you can't touch the `/www` directory? Isn't that the only place you are suppose to touch? :)

Comment: @nem Yes, that's pretty much true and I know it sounds a bit nuts. The client has had a web app built that they want to convert into an Android app and PhoneGap allowed me to easily do so without some of the issues I encountered setting it up as just a WebView but now I might revert back to building it all myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the webview after it finishes loading and inject some JS to render the connection status in the webview.

Something like (using jquery for example):

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:$('body').append('<div style=\"position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;\">STATUS HERE</div>')");
```